# Diseño responsivo carrusel Bootstrap 5 y mostrar imágenes diferentes

Tags: css, bootstrap, responsive

Tengo un carrusel con Bootstrap 5, en la PC se ve bien pero cuando se visualiza en un dispositivo móvil la altura del carrusel cambia y las imágenes se ven alargadas.

¿Alguien sabe cómo corregir el tamaño para los dispositivos móviles? Y si es posible mostrar imágenes diferentes en la versión PC y dispositivos móviles.

```
<style>
.midon img{
  height: 76vh;
}
```

```
<div class="midon">
    <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="/assets/img/hero-carousel/Banner7.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/assets/img/hero-carousel/Banner11.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/assets/img/hero-carousel/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/assets/img/hero-carousel/4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="/assets/img/hero-carousel/5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Si es posible y hay diferentes formas de hacerlo, desde usar la clase [`img-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/) de Bootstrap hasta usar diferentes imágenes dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo. Haz consultado o investigado en la documentación de Bootstrap?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Claro, he revisado la documentación pero no es muy clara que digamos, al menos no para el carrusel. Igual si tienes alguna recomendación te lo agradecería.